# Percorrer array com indice string

Tags: javascript, array, for

Estou tentando percorrer um array onde o índice retornado é string (são nomes). Eu sei percorrer quando eles vem com 0,1,2,3... mas com string estou com dificuldades. O retorno é o seguinte:

```
Aatrox: {version: "10.3.1", id: "Aatrox", key: "266", name: "Aatrox", title: "the Darkin Blade", …}
Ahri: {version: "10.3.1", id: "Ahri", key: "103", name: "Ahri", title: "the Nine-Tailed Fox", …}
Akali: {version: "10.3.1", id: "Akali", key: "84", name: "Akali", …}

// e assim vai 150 linhas mais o menos.
```

Como eu posso passar uma por uma e pegar somente o `name` e o `key` ? Tentei criar esse código abaixo, porém ele não funciona.

```
this.http.get('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.3.1/data/en_US/champion.json').subscribe((resC) => {

    var champions = JSON.parse(resC._body)

    console.log(champions.data) // aqui retorna a lista inteira, mas preciso das keys e names somente. da pra fazer ['Aatrox'], mas como coloca no for pra rodar sozinho sem especificar o nome do campeão? 

    for(const char of champions.data) {
        console.log(char)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Pelo o que eu pude observar, o retorno que você fala ser um Array é na verdade um objeto. A estrutura de um Array e um objeto são bastante diferentes como você ver nesse exemplo abaixo:

```
myArray = ["Katarina", "Teemo", "Veigar"] // Array com meus mains <3

// Abaixo é um objeto contendo chaves e valores. Dentro dessas chaves 
// (katarina, teemo e veigar) há outro objetos que contém mais chaves e valores.

myObject = {
    katarina: {skin: "Mercenária", lane: "mid"},
    teemo: {skin: "Coelhinho", lane: "top"},
    veigar: {skin: null, lane: "mid"}
}
```

Perceba que diferentemente de um Array, os objetos são criados utilizando chaves (`{}`) e os itens do objeto possuem chave e valor separador pelo sinal de dois pontos (`:`).

Quando se trata de um objeto, nós não devemos pensar em obter um valor através de um índice (posição), e sim através de uma chave. Para eu obter o valor de `skin` do objeto que vem do atributo `katarina` por exemplo, eu devo fazer o seguinte:

```
console.log(myObject.katarina.skin); // Imprime "Mercenária"

// É possível também acessar o atributo desta forma (bastante parecido com Arrays mas 
// ao invés de se passar um índice, você deve passar uma chave).

console.log(myObject["katarina"]["skin"]);
```

Para percorrer as chaves de um objeto em JavaScript utilizando `for`, nós devemos utilizar o operador `in` ao invés de `of` que serve para percorre cada chave do objeto. Veja abaixo:

```
for (let champ in myObject){
    let skin = myObject[champ].skin;
    console.log(`Eu possuo a skin ${skin} para o campeão ${champ}`);
}
```

O operador `of` só é utilizado para percorrer elementos de Arrays, então se você tiver um Array de objetos como o exemplo abaixo, você pode percorrer ele utilizando o `of` e depois utilizar o `in` para percorrer os atributos de cada objeto.

```
for (const objeto of arrayDeObjetos){
    for (let chave in objeto){
        // Código ...
    }
}
```